# Console command for completing Valuable minerals quest

Tags: mass-effect

In Mass Effect is there a console command to add minerals to complete the Valuable Minerals quest?

Comment: well if you are going to cheat, why not just edit your minerals in me2, since completing that quest in a carry over just gives you some mineral bonus in me2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a console command to complete this quest. However, [here is a full guide](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/UNC:_Valuable_Minerals) with the specific locations of each of the minerals.

The alternative is to use a saved game editor for Mass Effect 2 to edit the number of each mineral that you have.

If the purpose of completing this question is to maximise the experience you gain in a single playthrough, you can use the `GiveXP x` command (for example: `GiveXP 100` to add 100 experience) in the conosole.